# Unity 3D First Person Controller Script Reference

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference, controller

The FPS Controller Script can be found in Unity Standard Assets folder under Characters/FirstPersonCharacters. I added it to an object called Player. And when I want to pause the game (I've done a pause menu UI), I don't like that it still follows the mouse on the screen, so I want to freeze that rotation. Since I use the free rigidbody version, the RigidbodyConstrains does not work. I need to get a reference to that script to write `.enabled = false;` But it does not work, the Unity does not recognize it. I wrote:

`GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;`

But it does not work, even if I import UnityStandardAssets(I mean in the script: `using UnityStandardAssets;`)
I've tried a lot of other solutions, but I can't find the right one! Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

[vs2019error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcIvY.png)

[inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNC1K.png)

Comment: you speak about name and using a function which uses tagname, have you put the name in Tag?

Comment: That is alright, I also put the tag "Player" onto the Player object.

Comment: The GetComponent is not fine, it does not find any component called "FirstPersonController", even if I have the script called like this (from standard assets I repeat) attached to the player object

Comment: i dont see problem this line of code disable the script, so you confirm you dont see the script enabled in inspector after running the program?  you have no null reference if you break the line of code in 2 parts   var go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); (go no null) then var b = go.GetComponent... (the value have to be false?   just one last question, you do this action in another script than fpsController script?

Comment: Yes, I do this in another script than FirstPersonController.cs. I work in VS 2019 so it underlines with red the errors. It underlines between < and >. I'll edit the question and attach a screenshot.

Comment: could you show a screen with the gameobject Player please? where the fpscontroller scipt is defined

Comment: Of course, it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested in my visualstudio 2017  i have to add that line:

```
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
```

so i have taken the script directly from folder standard Asset

if you see into the script you have this line:

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
```

you have to precise the path where to find the class

this line is proposed by VisualStudio 2017, dunno why not by visual studio 2019

Comment: i suggest you to put GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") in a GameObject variable in Start() method, because FindGameObjectWithTag is not very fast..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else in the future coming across this, the current firstpersoncontroller script only requires that you add

```
using StarterAssets;
```

and then you can use GetComponent()